# How solve this linux server- Warning: copy() [function.copy]: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php

how to solve this:

```
 Warning: copy() [function.copy]: open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(http://pendufun.com/muzicpc/dload.php?id=443936&b=hq&cat=Hindi-Movies)
 is not within the allowed path(s): (D:/INETPUB/VHOSTS//runmaza.in\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\runmaza.in\httpdocs\viruwap\download.php on line 31 Your Hosting does not allow copy function
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open an external URL address, but you have `allow_url_fopen` disabled in your php configuration. If you can modify the `php.ini` then simply do:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: Would the same restriction be in effect for file_get_contents()?

Comment: @Mike They are all controlled by `allow_url_fopen` when using any file  function to opener a pointer in a remote file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is about `open_basedir` not `allow_url_fopen`.  `open_basedir` restrictions ***should*** have ***no*** effect on `http://` URLs, but there is a longstanding bug in the implementation of `copy` in the Windows PHP build which prevents it working with URLs when `open_basedir` is set, regardless of the value of `allow_url_fopen`.  There is no problem with Linux.  The title of the question is wrong - those are clearly Windows paths, not Linux paths.